# How to copy std::string to std::string with parameters?

Tags: c++, string, std

I can't solve the problem with the copying strings with parameters.
I have found the way to do it with `char *` pointers, but they are actually wasting extra resources:

```
using namespace std;
...
string word, halfWord_0S, halfWord_1S;
char halfWord_0[100], halfWord_1[100];
...
if ((i % 2) == 0)
    {
        word.copy(halfWord_0, (i / 2), 0);
        word.copy(halfWord_1, (i / 2), ((i / 2)));
    }   else    {
        word.copy(halfWord_0, ((i / 2) + 1), 0);
        word.copy(halfWord_1, ((i / 2) + 1), (i / 2));
    }
    halfWord_0S = halfWord_0;
    halfWord_1S = halfWord_1;
...
```

I want to work only with std::string without `char *`. Is this possible in this case?

Comment: What is `std::word`?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this snippet:

```
std::string base = "some text";
std::string half = base.substr(0, base.length()/2);
std::string secondHalf = base.substr(base.length()/2);
```

Comment: What is variable `s`?